# Bootstrap modal won't show when applied display:none and then display:block to parent div

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Here's my code. Now I am changing the properties of the div with class col-sm-6 on click of a button which turns display:none using jquery. On click of another button I change it back to block but the modal doesn't open. The background gets dark but window won't open. Basically the outer most div gets display:none and then display:block. But the modal is never changed. What could be the possible solutions. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" id="challange">
                        <div class="alert card alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                            <div class="cardAlert-header">
                                <h5 class="title">Challange</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
                                    <i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <div class="view">
                                    <a class="rounded mx-auto d-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ChartForChallenge">
                                        <img src="img/dashboard/walking-the-dog.svg" class="rounded mx-auto d-block">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Central Modal Medium Warning -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="ChartForChallenge" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-notify modal-info modal-lg" role="document">
                                <!--Content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <!--Header-->
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                                        <p class="heading lead">Pet Activity</p>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--Body-->
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <!-- Nav tabs -->
                                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs md-pills pills-default" role="tablist">
                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#Giorno" role="tab">Giorno</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Settmana" role="tab">Settmana</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <!-- Tab panels -->
                                            <div class="main-content">
                                                <p class="head">Ogg 10:47AM</p>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                        <img src="img/dashboard/walking-the-dog.svg" height="120px" width="120px">
                                                        <span class="title">Marco</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                        <img src="img/dashboard/dog.svg" height="120px" width="120px">
                                                        <span class="title">Fiamma</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tab-content">
                                                <!--Panel 1-->
                                                <div class="tab-pane fade in show active" id="Giorno" role="tabpanel">
                                                    <br>
                                                    <div id="petHealth" class="chart">
                                                        <svg style="min-height: 220px;"></svg>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--/.Panel 1-->
                                                <!--Panel 3-->
                                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Settmana" role="tabpanel">
                                                    <br>
                                                    <div id="petHealthDetails" class="chart">
                                                        <svg></svg>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--/.Panel 3-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--Footer-->
                                    <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            <span>8</span>
                                            <p>Number passed</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            <span>18</span>
                                            <p>Number passed</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--/.Content-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this code if you want is this way.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" id="challange">
      <div class="alert card alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
         <div class="cardAlert-header">
            <h5 class="title">Challange</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="card-block">
            <div class="view">
               <a class="rounded mx-auto d-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ChartForChallenge">
               <img src="img/dashboard/walking-the-dog.svg" class="rounded mx-auto d-block">
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Central Modal Medium Warning -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="ChartForChallenge" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog modal-notify modal-info modal-lg" role="document">
            <!--Content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
               <!--Header-->
               <div class="modal-header">
                  <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                  <p class="heading lead">Pet Activity</p>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">&times;</span>
                  </button>
               </div>
               <!--Body-->
               <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="text-center">
                     <!-- Nav tabs -->
                     <ul class="nav nav-tabs md-pills pills-default" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                           <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#Giorno" role="tab">Giorno</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                           <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Settmana" role="tab">Settmana</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                     <!-- Tab panels -->
                     <div class="main-content">
                        <p class="head">Ogg 10:47AM</p>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-6">
                              <img src="img/dashboard/walking-the-dog.svg" height="120px" width="120px">
                              <span class="title">Marco</span>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-6">
                              <img src="img/dashboard/dog.svg" height="120px" width="120px">
                              <span class="title">Fiamma</span>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="tab-content">
                        <!--Panel 1-->
                        <div class="tab-pane fade in show active" id="Giorno" role="tabpanel">
                           <br>
                           <div id="petHealth" class="chart">
                              <svg style="min-height: 220px;"></svg>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.Panel 1-->
                        <!--Panel 3-->
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Settmana" role="tabpanel">
                           <br>
                           <div id="petHealthDetails" class="chart">
                              <svg></svg>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.Panel 3-->
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <!--Footer-->
               <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-6">
                     <span>8</span>
                     <p>Number passed</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6">
                     <span>18</span>
                     <p>Number passed</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!--/.Content-->
         </div>
      </div>
      <button style="margin:7px 15px 17px 0;" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ChartForChallenge">Click To Open Modal</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this code works and what it does differently than the poster's code?